# Configuring Kensington Slimblade in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xinput

I just got a Kensigton Slimblade Trackball and I'm trying to configure it. I'm adapting it from my old Logitech Marble configuration.

I want the configuration to be:

- Left-Bottom: Left click
- Left-Top: Backward
- Right-Top: Right click and ball scroll lock
- Right-Bottom: Middle click

The configuration I could set until now is:

- Left-Bottom: Left click
- Left-Top: Middle click
- Right-Top: Right click and ball scroll lock
- Right-Bottom: Backward

This is my configuration script:

```
xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Middle Button Emulation" 8 1   

xinput set-button-map "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" 1 2 8 4 5 6 7 

xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8 8
xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 8 6 7 4 5
xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 16 300
```

Before running this script, `xev` reports button numbers as:

```
Left-Bottom: 1, Left-Top: 2, Right-Top: 8, Right-Botom: 3
```

After running this script:

```
Left-Bottom: 1, Left-Top: 2, Right-Top: 8, Right-Botom: 8
```

So AFAIK, `xinput set-button-map` changes button order. In [this](https://wiki.mbirth.de/know-how/software/linux/remapping-mouse-buttons.html) page, I learned that the 2nd value corresponds to the middle mouse button, and the 8th to the Thumb1 (normally related to backward function). So I thought I should just use number 3 as the 2nd element and 2 as the 8th element like this:

```
xinput set-button-map "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" 1 3 8 4 5 6 7 2
```

but now the top-left button has right-click function and left-bottom is disabled. `xev` now reports

```
Left-Bottom: 1, Left-Top: 3, Right-Top: 2, Right-Botom: 8.
```

Anyone knows how I set the configuration as I intend ? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few minutes after I post the question I found the answer. Here goes in case anyone needs it (configuration for Mint 18/Ubuntu 16.04):

```
xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Middle Button Emulation" 8 0
7 8 9 
xinput set-button-map "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" 1 8 2 4 5 6 7 3 2
xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8 8
xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 8 6 7 4 5
xinput set-int-prop "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 16 300
```

**Edit**

After upgrading for Mint 19 (at home) and Ubuntu 18.04 (at office) I found the configuration above doesn't work. 18.04 uses a different library for these kind of devices (libinput) and even if I reinstalled Evdev some options don't work. After a painful search I found the solution. 
Create a a file with .conf extension in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` folder. In my case I named it `10-slimblade.conf`. Put this configuration inside the file:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball"
        MatchProduct "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 8 2 4 5 6 7 3 2"
        Option "ScrollButton" "8"
        Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
        Option "MiddleEmulation" "on"
EndSection
```

Restart session, and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks so much! Just to add on a bit, I was able to find that these are how the buttons are on the trackball:

```
---------
| 2 | 8 |
---------
| 1 | 3 |
---------
```

And this is the order they are in the `ButtonMapping` string:

```
LeftClick MiddleClick RightClick ScrollUp ScrollDown ScrollLeft ScrollRight Back Forward
```

So, for me, I just wanted right and left on the bottom row, with back top left and middle top right:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball"
    MatchProduct "Kensington Kensington Slimblade Trackball"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 9"
    Option "ScrollButton" "8"
    Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
EndSection
```

The documentation here is non-existent, so this is what I could piece together by running `xev -event mouse`.

---

Here is a map from button ID to its function:

| Button | Function |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | left click |
| 2 | middle click |
| 3 | right click |
| 4 | scroll up |
| 5 | scroll down |
| 6 | scroll left |
| 7 | scroll right |
| 8 | back |
| 9 | forward |

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful, thanks guys! :) Had to modify slightly to make it work for me, though. Since on my system (Ubuntu 18.04) xinput reports the trackball like this:

```
$ xinput list | grep Kensington
⎜   ↳ Kensington Slimblade Trackball            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I had to modify `MatchProduct` from your examples above to make that work for me. Also I slimmed it down a tiny bit. On my end it looks like this and that worked for me:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Kensington Slimblade Trackball"
    MatchProduct "Kensington Slimblade Trackball"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 9"
    Option "ScrollButton" "8"
    Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
EndSection
```

Comment: In "make it work" it's not clear what "it" refers to. Maybe improve than answer. And you don't have to add "thanks"; upvote instead.